# Keepalived - VIP on device different from one where VRRP instance configured

Tags: keepalived

I have 2 VMs with Linux and keepalived installed. Their hostnames are *master* and *slave*. Each VM has 2 network interfaces configured for different subnets:

- master:

  - eth1 - 192.168.1.101/24
  - eth2 - 192.168.56.101/24
- slave:

  - eth1 - 192.168.1.102/24
  - eth2 - 192.168.56.102/24

On each node I configured one `vrrp_instance` using interface `eth1`:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    ...
    interface eth1
    ...
}
```

And I assigned one VIP for each subnet - one per interface:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  ...
  virtual_ipaddress {
      192.168.1.250/32  dev eth1 label eth1:vip0
      192.168.56.250/32 dev eth2 label eth2:vip0
    }
  ...
}
```

So, whole configs are:

- master:

  ```
  vrrp_instance VI_1 {
      state MASTER
      interface eth1
      virtual_router_id 1
      priority 100
      advert_int 1
      authentication {
          auth_type PASS
          auth_pass HURRDURR
      }


    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.250/32  dev eth1 label eth1:vip0
        192.168.56.250/32 dev eth2 label eth2:vip0
      }
  }
  ```
- slave:

  ```
  vrrp_instance VI_1 {
      state BACKUP
      interface eth1
      virtual_router_id 1
      priority 99
      advert_int 1
      authentication {
          auth_type PASS
          auth_pass HURRDURR
      }


    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.250/32  dev eth1 label eth1:vip0
        192.168.56.250/32 dev eth2 label eth2:vip0
      }
  }
  ```

**A question:** could someone please tell me if there are pitfalls with a similar setup (on condition that VRRP multicast is allowed for the interface specified in option `interface <interface name>`).

As far as I understood, option `interface <interface name>` is used only for intercommunication between keepalived instances, and in fact, it specified which interface keepalived will use to send multicast traffic to negotiate which one should be a leader at the moment. And it should not affect configured VIPs (on condition that I configured them properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized at least one pitfall of a similar configuration. In case of network problems with interface `eth2` on `master` server, VIP assigned on `eth1` will not be moved to `slave` because VRRP instance configured via network on  `eth1` of both servers.

Therefore I think that a similar configuration is not recommended. VIP should be assigned to the same interface where VRRP instance was configured.

Correct configuration:

- master:

  ```
  vrrp_instance VI_1 {
      state MASTER
      interface eth1
      virtual_router_id 1
      priority 100
      advert_int 1
      authentication {
          auth_type PASS
          auth_pass HURRDURR
      }


    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.250/32  dev eth1 label eth1:vip0
      }
  }

  vrrp_instance VI_2 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth2
    virtual_router_id 2
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass HURRDURR
    }


  virtual_ipaddress {
      192.168.56.250/32 dev eth2 label eth2:vip0
    }
  }
  ```
- slave:

  ```
  vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 1
    priority 99
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass HURRDURR
    }


  virtual_ipaddress {
      192.168.1.250/32  dev eth1 label eth1:vip0
    }
  }

  vrrp_instance VI_2 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth2
    virtual_router_id 2
    priority 99
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass HURRDURR
    }


  virtual_ipaddress {
      192.168.56.250/32 dev eth2 label eth2:vip0
    }
  }
  ```